# ArchUnit rule to check if class is accessed within same package or sub-packages?

Tags: java, annotations, archunit

I have classes annotated by my custom annotation `@Inner`.

I would like to create a rule for `ArchUnit` to detect if classes annotated with this particular annotation are accessed within the same package or sub-packages.

For example:

package: `com.example.my.package`

Contains class: `MyInner` that is annotated with `@Inner`

So the rule should check if `MyInner` is accessed only from `com.example.my.package` or `com.example.my.package.baz`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found such rule:

```java
public class DependencyRules {

    @PublicAPI(usage = ACCESS)
    public static ArchCondition<JavaClass> accessClassesThatResideInAnUpperPackage() {
        return new AccessClassesThatResideInAnUpperPackageCondition();
    }

    private static class AccessClassesThatResideInAnUpperPackageCondition extends ArchCondition<JavaClass> {
        AccessClassesThatResideInAnUpperPackageCondition() {
            super("access classes that reside in an upper package");
        }

        @Override
        public void check(final JavaClass clazz, final ConditionEvents events) {
            for (JavaAccess<?> access : clazz.getAccessesFromSelf()) {
                boolean callToSuperPackage = isCallToSuperPackage(access.getOriginOwner(), access.getTargetOwner());
                events.add(new SimpleConditionEvent(access, callToSuperPackage, access.getDescription()));
            }
        }

        private boolean isCallToSuperPackage(JavaClass origin, JavaClass target) {
            String originPackageName = getOutermostEnclosingClass(origin).getPackageName();
            String targetSubPackagePrefix = getOutermostEnclosingClass(target).getPackageName() + ".";
            return originPackageName.startsWith(targetSubPackagePrefix);
        }

        private JavaClass getOutermostEnclosingClass(JavaClass javaClass) {
            while (javaClass.getEnclosingClass().isPresent()) {
                javaClass = javaClass.getEnclosingClass().get();
            }
            return javaClass;
        }
    }
}
```

Source: https://github.com/TNG/ArchUnit/commit/5f7fadc0f67ba61e2c9fe94bfe494303780c37d7